# Difficulty moving Gradle configuration to an external script

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I am trying to move some parts of my Gradle build script to an external configuration file that can be shared among projects.  Here is an example with the *Detekt* plugin:

### Current Code

*build.gradle.kts* (condensed to only the relevant parts)

```
plugins{
    id("io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt").version("1.19.0-RC1")
}
...
detekt{
   ...
}
```

### What I'm trying to do

*build.gradle.kts*

```
apply(File("common.gradle.kts"))
```

*common.gradle.kts*

```
plugins {
    id("io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt").version("1.19.0-RC1")
}

detekt{
   ...
}
```

but when I do this I get this error:

```
<my_project>\common.gradle.kts:7:1: Unresolved reference: detekt
```

So the `plugin` section doesn't appear to be doing anything.  And just to be clear, this plugin does not need anything in `dependencies` section, it works fine inside `build.gradle.kts` with only the `plugin` declaration.

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 1):

I am using it with normal Groovy Gradle scripts like this:

```
# detekt.gradle
apply plugin: 'io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt'

tasks.detekt.jvmTarget = "1.8"

detekt {
    buildUponDefaultConfig = true
    input = files("${rootProject.projectDir}/app/src")
    config = files("${rootProject.projectDir}/detekt.yml")

    reports {
        html.enabled = true
        xml.enabled = true
    }
}
```

```
# build.gradle
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath libs.android.gradle
        classpath libs.kotlin.gradle
        classpath libs.detekt
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

subprojects {
    apply from: rootProject.file('detekt.gradle')
    apply from: rootProject.file('ktlint.gradle')
    apply from: rootProject.file('spotless.gradle')
    ...
}
```